# Species-ID: What kind of bug is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

What kind of bug is this?

Size: About the size of a pencil tip

When was it found: spring time

Where was it found: In northeastern USA, inside the bathroom of our house

Comment: Anyone trying to answer will need more information: size, location, time of year.

Comment: About the size of a pencil tip, spring time, in the northeast, inside the bathroom of our house

Comment: The northeast of what? The stereotype is that Americans typically assume it is obvious to anyone that the coordinates are relative to the USA (no offense), so I edited your post to add these info assuming you meant northeast USA. Please correct it if this is not what you meant

Comment: Yes, Northeast USA

Answer (score 3):

It could be a cockroach nimph. Distinctive characteristics:The overall shape and size, the long antenae, the segmented abdomen and the visible rear cerci.